# How to count number of clients who have not paid their's first loan repayment in time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table which looks like

```
ContractID | RepaymentNumber | MaturityDateID | PaymentDateID | Amount
242105     | 1               | 20170605       | 20170604      | 4825
322105     | 32              | 20170608       | 20170601      | 825
245105     | 6               | 20170611       | 20170804      | 148
578105     | 11              | 20170711       | 20170809      | 0
578185     | 21              | 20170712       | 19000101      | 3541
```

Where MaturityDateID is an date (in INT) to which a client should pay his loan according to his repaymentschedule and paymentDateID is a date in INT when he really send the payment. Amount = 0 means a client has a postpone in his repaymentschedule. RepaymentNumber is a count number of client's payment.

Now, I need to count a number of clients who's first repayment for a loan is PaymentDateID > MaturityDateID. The issue is the can have countless number of postpones, so for the first repayment, the column RepaymentNumber can be arbitary.

I've tried:

```
;WITH Nots AS (
    SELECT
        c.ApplicationID
        --,rs.Amount
        ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rs.Amount) AS RankID
    FROM    
        dim.Contract c
        JOIN dim.Application a ON c.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID
        JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON a.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId   
        JOIN dim.CreditAdvisor ca ON a.OriginalCreditAdvisorID = ca.CreditAdvisorId 
        JOIN dim.RepaymentSchedule rs   ON  c.ContractID = rs.ContractID
    WHERE
        ((cal.CalendarYear >= 2016) AND (rs.MaturityDateID < 20170811)) -- Since given year to this date
        AND ((rs.PaymentDateID = 19000101) OR (rs.PaymentDateID > rs.MaturityDateID))
    GROUP BY
        1
)

    SELECT *
    FROM Nots
    WHERE RankID > 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "client"?  I don't see any such column in your sample data.  Also, you show a table, and then you have a complicated query with many tables.  Which is actually representative of your question?

Comment: In order to help you we really need to see any relevant fields in other tables (which there clearly are because you're joining to them in your sample query.

Comment: @Gordon Obviously, I can't write out all our database tables in the question for you. Client is a human being who have a loan in our company.

Comment: Can you at least tell us which table you showed? I would have guessed contract but you try to select `c.applicationid` which is not in the table provided

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is just that postpones, defined as those rows with Amount = 0 don't count as payments and you want the first "real" payment, you would just need to exclude those rows with Amount = 0.  The `WHERE` statement would then be:

```
WHERE
        ((cal.CalendarYear >= 2016) AND (rs.MaturityDateID < 20170811)) -- Since given year to this date
        AND ((rs.PaymentDateID = 19000101) OR (rs.PaymentDateID > rs.MaturityDateID))
        AND rs.Amount > 0
```